# Some gtk apps have black border in Plasma

Tags: kde, elementary-os, gtk3

Now I'm using KDE plasma as my DE, and I really like the style of elementaryOS. So I use a theme inspired by elementaryOS. But in some gtk apps, it has black border and some circle buttons are out of shape. btw, not only elementaryOS theme, but also some other theme have this problem.

[image: this is pantheon-video and it has black edge and some circle buttons are out of shape.]

So what could I do to remove this annoying black border.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK%2B#Client-side_decorations  This doesn't work for me.

Comment: Which kde-plasma version, which gtk+ version ?

Answer (score 0):

Within the Plasma Desktop you can specifically alter the way GTK applications appear.

You can open System Settings and under Appearance you will find Application Style. Within Application Style, you have the ability to change the theme and related for GTK/Gnome apps.

For continuity, pick the same theme for GTK apps that you're using for system-wide looks.

Good Luck!!!